# GSon Java: (De)Serialize Array containing POJO containing Arrays of String

Tags: java, arrays, json, nested, gson

This seems like a common problem and there's plenty of stuff on this, but nothing I have tried has worked so far. I have a class:

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> types;

    public Item() {
        super();
    }

    public Item(String name, ArrayList<String> types {
        this.name = name;
        this.types = types;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public setTypes(ArrayList<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }
}
```

I have a wrapper class:

```
public class ItemData {
    private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

On my server, I build and serialize the object like so:
Server.java:

```
...
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<>();
types.add("Type A");
types.add("Type B");
items = Stream.of(
    new Item("Item One", types),
    new Item("Item Two", types))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Gson objGson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
ItemData data = new ItemData();
data.setData((ArrayList<Item> items);
return objGson.toJson(data);
```

This works great, producing output like this:

```
{ "items" : [ { "name": "Item One", "types": [ "Type A", "Type B" ] },
{ "name": "Item Two", "types": [ "Type A", "Type B" ] } ] }
```

My client has the same code for the items, and I can deserialize the object with this code:
client.java

```
...
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Item>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Item> items = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

This also "works", using the wrapper class:

```
ItemData data = new Gson().fromJson(json, ItemData.class);
items = data.getItems();
```

So does this:

```
items = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(json, Item[].class));
```

My problem is that even though the sub-array of ListArray (types) shows up in the json produced by the server, it is never properly decoded by the client. The client just gets null for types.

I have looked at just about every post on this and have tried various things with simple json, json.org, jackson, and gson, and I'm pulling my hair out. Surely this can't be that complicated. I see various posts online that purport how to do this, but none of them that I have tried have successfully decoded the subarray.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So `new Gson().fromJson(json, ItemData.class);` this works? What's actually the issue? You need the wrapper object to deserialize the json you posted. Without it, you'd have to write a custom deserializer. If you want to deserialize a json like `[ { "name": "Item One", "types": [ "Type A", "Type B" ] },
{ "name": "Item Two", "types": [ "Type A", "Type B" ] } ]`, then `gson.fromJson(json, listType);` should work too.

Comment: Yes, it does work, more or less. The problem is that the list of strings is never deserialized.

Comment: ok, I must not be understanding something because this works fine for me.

Comment: This was a simplified example. I went back and conformed my actual code to it and it works, so I must have been doing something stupid. Thanks for the feedback! It was a helpful exercise and good to know that what i was trying to do was actually correct.